# How to show up a caption when the mouse arrow stays on the checkbutton

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

That's very difficult to explain. In my program there are two Checkbutton (this could be their name, however i'm talking about the square that can be flagged). I'd like that when the mouse lays on them appears a little caption. It would be better if I could set a time before the message appears.
Thank you!

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='lightblue')
root.title("#1")
root.geometry("180x60+350+220")
request = StringVar() #i did the same with all other variables
inte=["explorer" , "Explorer","rete"]
chro=["chrome" ,"Chrome","ricerca",]
of=["openoffice","foglio bianco","scrittura"]
dia = Entry(root, textvariable = request, bg="white").grid(row=0,column=1)
chk = Checkbutton(root,text="Ricerca in internet", textvariable = fla, 
bg="lightblue").grid(row=0,column=0) #first checkbutton
chk1 = Checkbutton(root,text="Ricerca in internet", textvariable = ran, 
bg="lightblue").grid(row=0,column=2) #the second one
def apri():     
     if request.get().strip() in inte:
     subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe']) #i did the same with all other lists 
else:
          webbrowser.open("https://www.google.it/search?q={0}&oq={0}&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61j0l3.1306j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8".format(request.get().strip()))

bott = Button(root, text="Cerca", command = apri, 
bg="white").grid(row=1,column=1)
```

that's my program, I took one example from any step

Comment: you are talking about tooltips, many libraries implement them, which one are you using in your project ? Also it's less difficult to explain with some code...

Comment: I'm using tkinter, I'll edit my post as soon as I can

Comment: i think it's not available in the standard tkinter, but you can find many examples of custom classes to handle that. try some queries with "tooltip and tkinter"

Comment: perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will achieve what you're looking for:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.check = Checkbutton(self.root)
        self.check.pack()
        self.check.bind("<Enter>", self.enter)
        self.check.bind("<Leave>", self.leave)
    def enter(self, *args):
        self.top = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        self.top.geometry("+%d+%d" % (self.root.winfo_rootx()+self.check.winfo_x()+self.check.winfo_width(), self.root.winfo_rooty()+self.check.winfo_y()))
        self.label = Label(self.top, text="Lorem Ipsum", bg="white")
        self.label.pack()
    def leave(self, *args):
        self.top.destroy()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Now let's break it down.

We use `.bind("<Enter>", *callback*)` and `.bind("<Leave>", *callback*)` to create a callback whenever the mouse enters the widget's bounding box or leaves it respectively.

We then create the two callbacks `enter()` and `leave()`.



Within `enter()` we do the following:

1) Create a `Toplevel` widget.

2) Use `wm_overrideredirect()` which we're really only using to prevent the window having a top bar and border.

3) Set the windows position.

4) Create a pack a `Label` widget into the `Toplevel`.



Let's break down step 3.

So we're creating a geometry value equivalent to `+n1+n2` where `n1` and `n2` are two separate numbers (Which can be the same) and where `n1` is the x coordinate and `n2` is the y coordinate. To get the x coordinate we add together the below:

The value of `.winfo_rootx()` when used on `root` which returns the x coordinate of the root window on the screen.

The value of `.winfo_x()` when used on `check` which returns the x coordinate of the left edge of the widget relative to the root window.

The value of `.winfo_width()` when used on `check` which returns the width of the widget.

These three values places the x coordinate of the left side of the window equal to the right edge of the widget no matter where it's drawn and where the window is.



To get the y coordinate we add together the below:

The value of `.winfo_rooty()` when used on `root` which returns the y coordinate of the root window on the screen.

The value of `.winfo_y()` when used on `check` which returns the y coordinate of the top edge of the widget relative to the root window.

These two values places the y coordinate of the top side of the window equal to the top edge of the widget no matter where it's drawn and where the window is.



`leave()` is an awful lot simpler, when we call this we simply destroy the `Toplevel` widget.

Comment: the main problem is that I don't know what is a class, and I don't find a good guide in my language. I don't understand english guide because of my english level that's just good for a colloquial speech. I should ask my father but he doesn't write a code since 1991. However thanks, but I can only copy paste the code without understanding enough

Comment: Classes are just python's object orientated tool. Look up "Object-Orientated Programming" and find a guide in your native language. Also, if this answer answers your question, please can you mark it as accepted so that other users can use it in the future.